# Part of function Component wont render in React even though same code works for another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a React website. I am using a function component to render a piece of code by mapping the array. This is the code

```
import React from 'react'
import './DedicatedServer.css'

function DedicatedServer() {
    const features = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Performance",
            text: "Random text long enough to take you anywhere. I am not sure what to write right now but it will come out to be good"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Secure",
            text: "Random text long enough to take you anywhere. I am not sure what to write right now but it will come out to be good"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "Speed",
            text: "Random text long enough to take you anywhere. I am not sure what to write right now but it will come out to be good"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title: "Price",
            text: "Random text long enough to take you anywhere. I am not sure what to write right now but it will come out to be good"
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            title: "Uptime",
            text: "Random text long enough to take you anywhere. I am not sure what to write right now but it will come out to be good"
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            title: "Live Support",
            text: "Random text long enough to take you anywhere. I am not sure what to write right now but it will come out to be good"
        },
    ]
    return (
        <div className="dedicated-server-container">
            <div>
                <h2 className="dedicated-server-heading">100GBPS for your needs</h2>
                <p className="dedicated-server-text">100GBPS provides you with unrivalled performance, support, and reliability</p>
                <p className="dedicated-server-text">Everything you can think of when you want to buy a dedicated server</p>
                <div className="dedicated-features">
                    {features.map((feature, i) => {
                        <div key={i} className="dedicated-feature">
                            <h3 className="feature-heading">{feature.title}</h3>
                            <p className="feature-text">{feature.text}</p>
                        </div>
                    })}
                    <h1>Hello there!</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DedicatedServer
```

Everything else works as expected but the block inside the curly braces does not render. I checked the console and there are no errors either.

I checked out some answers on Stack overflow related to problem with rendering but I am following everything and I am not really sure what am I missing.

I am using the same method in another file and it works just fine. I know this is a pretty simple problem and I am missing something really silly here but can you point out what is the issue here?

This is the piece of code for the other file and it works just fine.

```
import React from 'react'
import cloudlinux from './vector-logo/cloudlinux.svg'
import litespeed from './vector-logo/litespeed.svg'
import letsencrypt from './vector-logo/lets-encrypt.svg'
import cloudflare from './vector-logo/cloudflare.svg'
import cpanel from './vector-logo/cpanel.svg'
import './Vendors.css'

function Vendors() {
    const vendorList = [
        {  
            id: 1,
            title: "Cloudflare",
            img: `${cloudflare}`
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "LiteSpeed",
            img: `${litespeed}`
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "Let's Encrypt",
            img: `${letsencrypt}`
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title: "Cloud Linux",
            img: `${cloudlinux}`
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            title: "cPanel",
            img: `${cpanel}`
        }        
    ]
    return (
        <div className="vendor-div">
                <h2 className="vendor-text">Our Vendors</h2>
            <div key={vendorList.id} className="vendors">
                {vendorList.map((vendors, index) => (
                    <img key={index} className="vendor-image" alt={vendors.title} src={vendors.img}/>    
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Vendors
```

This is the answer I found on stack overflow and I am guessing that this is not the problem here.
[Link to the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838937/component-wont-render-in-react)

Comment: It's a syntax problem in your `map` function. Either replace the curly braces by `(...)`, as in your second example - or put a `return` inside the `{...}` before the JSX output. As you have it now, your `map` isn't actually returning anything. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the created div from inside the map like this

```
{features.map((feature, i) => {
                        
    return <div key={i} className="dedicated-feature">
                            
        <h3 className="feature-heading">{feature.title}</h3>
                            
        <p className="feature-text">{feature.text}</p>
                        
    </div>
})}
```

Alternatively you can use parenthesis instead of `{}` in the map functions. Parenthesis will implicitly return the JSX inside of them

```
{features.map((feature, i) => (
                        
    <div key={i} className="dedicated-feature">
                            
        <h3 className="feature-heading">{feature.title}</h3>
                            
        <p className="feature-text">{feature.text}</p>
                        
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: I see the problem now. Thanks a lot for the solution. Much appreciated.